# Exclude "@" sign from punctuationCharacterSet

Tags: nsrange, nscharacterset

I am trying to filter my attributedString this way, using this code. However, I want the `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` to include all of its original values EXCEPT for the "@" sign. How would I do this?

```
NSRange rangeSpace = [filteredText rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(range.location, filteredText.length - range.location)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *punctuationSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet];
[punctuationSet removeCharactersInString:@"@"];

NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(range.location, filteredText.length - range.location)

NSRange rangeSpace = [filteredText rangeOfCharacterFromSet:punctuationSet 
                                                   options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                                     range:searchRange];
```